# All nodeValue fields are None when parsing XML

Tags: python, xml, rss, minidom

I'm building a simple web-based RSS reader in Python, but I'm having trouble parsing the XML. I started out by trying some stuff in the Python command line.

```
>>> from xml.dom import minidom
>>> import urllib2 
>>> url ='http://www.digg.com/rss/index.xml'
>>> xmldoc = minidom.parse(urllib2.urlopen(url))
>>> channelnode = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("channel")
>>> channelnode = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("channel")
>>> titlenode = channelnode[0].getElementsByTagName("title")
>>> print titlenode[0]
<DOM Element: title at 0xb37440> 
>>> print titlenode[0].nodeValue 
None
```

I played around with this for a while, but the `nodeValue` of everything seems to be `None`. Yet if you look at the XML, there definitely are values there. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For RSS feeds you should try the [Universal Feed Parser](http://code.google.com/p/feedparser/) library. It simplifies the handling of RSS feeds immensly.

```
import feedparser
d = feedparser.parse('http://www.digg.com/rss/index.xml')
title = d.channel.title
```

Answer (score 10):

This is the syntax you are looking for:

```
>>> print titlenode[0].firstChild.nodeValue
digg.com: Stories / Popular
```

Note that the node value is a logical descendant of the node itself.