# Python: Using minidom to search for nodes with a certain text

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I am currently faced with XML that looks like this:

```
<ID>345754</ID>
```

This is contained within a hierarchy. I have parsed the xml, and wish to find the ID node by searching on "345754".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
xmldoc = minidom.parse('your.xml')
matchingNodes = [node for node in xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("id") if node.nodeValue == '345754']
```

See also:

- [How to get whole text of an Element in xml.minidom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666724/how-to-get-whole-text-of-an-element-in-xml-minidom)
- [All nodeValue fields are None when parsing XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479751/parsing-xml-with-python)

Comment: I'm fairly sure that won't work - have you tested it? nodeValue is usually set to 'None' on element nodes (as one of your links says). I've never found it any use - one has to drill down to the text node children.

Answer (score 10):

vartec's answer needs correcting (sorry I'm not sure I can do that), it should read:

```
xmldoc = xml.dom.minidom.parse('your.xml')
matchingNodes = [node for node in xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("ID") if 
node.firstChild.nodeValue == '345754']
```

Two things were wrong with it: (i) tag names are case sensitive so matching on `"id"` won't work and (ii) for an element node `.nodeValue` will be `None`, you need access to the text nodes that is inside the element node which contains the value you want.