# How to find a specific tag in an XML file and then access its parent tag with Python and minidom

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I'm trying to write some code that will search through an XML file of articles for a particular DOI contained within a tag. When it has found the correct DOI I'd like it to then access the `<title>` and `<abstract>` text for the article associated with that DOI.

My XML file is in this format:

```
<root>
 <article>
  <number>
   0 
  </number>
  <DOI>
   10.1016/B978-0-12-381015-1.00004-6 
  </DOI>
  <title>
   The patagonian toothfish biology, ecology and fishery. 
  </title>
  <abstract>
   lots of abstract text
  </abstract>
 </article>
 <article>
  ...All the article tags as shown above...
 </article>
</root>
```

I'd like the script to find the article with the DOI 10.1016/B978-0-12-381015-1.00004-6 (for example) and then for me to be able to access the `<title>` and `<abstract>` tags within the corresponding `<article>` tag.

So far I've tried to adapt code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706453/python-using-minidom-to-search-for-nodes-with-a-certain-text):

```
from xml.dom import minidom

datasource = open('/Users/philgw/Dropbox/PW-Honours-Project/Code/processed.xml')
xmldoc = minidom.parse(datasource)   

#looking for: 10.1016/B978-0-12-381015-1.00004-6

matchingNodes = [node for node in xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("DOI") if node.firstChild.nodeValue == '10.1016/B978-0-12-381015-1.00004-6']

for i in range(len(matchingNodes)):
    DOI = str(matchingNodes[i])
    print DOI
```

But I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing!

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

imho - just look it up in the python docs!
try this (not tested):

```
from xml.dom import minidom

xmldoc = minidom.parse(datasource)   

def get_xmltext(parent, subnode_name):
    node = parent.getElementsByTagName(subnode_name)[0]
    return "".join([ch.toxml() for ch in node.childNodes])

matchingNodes = [node for node in xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("article")
           if get_xmltext(node, "DOI") == '10.1016/B978-0-12-381015-1.00004-6']

for node in matchingNodes:
    print "title:", get_xmltext(node, "title")
    print "abstract:", get_xmltext(node, "abstract")
```

Comment: ok i see it now, you need to lookup parent first in the matchingNodes, I update it ... ok its updated now.

Comment: Thanks Jiri - this looks promising but at the moment it doesn't return any output when I try and test it. I've added the datasource line to your example, but nothing is being printed.

Comment: Scratch that - there was a problem with whitespace confusing the script, this works great - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is minidom a requirement? It would be quite easy to parse it with lxml and XPath.

```
from lxml import etree
datasource = open('/Users/philgw/Dropbox/PW-Honours-Project/Code/processed.xml').read()
tree = etree.fromstring(datasource)
path = tree.xpath("//article[DOI="10.1016/B978-0-12-381015-1.00004-6")
```

This will get you the article with the DOI specified.

Also, it seems that there is whitespace between the tags. I dunno if this because of the Stackoverflow formatting or not. This is probably why you cannot match it with minidom.